# Weird generics compile error

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have two classes, a base class and a child class. In the base class i define a generic virtual method:

```
protected virtual ReturnType Create<T>() where T : ReturnType {}
```

Then in my child class i try to do this:

```
protected override ReturnTypeChild Create<T>() // ReturnTypeChild inherits ReturnType
{ 
  return base.Create<T> as ReturnTypeChild; 
}
```

Visual studio gives this weird error:

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Create()'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ReturnType'.
```

Repeating the where clause on the child's override also gives an error:

```
Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly
```

So what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Should that be `protected override BarChild Foo<T>()`? Can you give proper names? Foo and Bar hurt my head.

Comment: And shouldn't it be return base.Foo<T> as BarChild();?

Comment: Your code has all kinds of problems (e.g. your overridden method is missing its generic parameter, your return statement has parens in the wrong place, etc.).  You are more likely to get helpful answers if you create a minimal reproduction of your problem that has all of the obvious issues fixed.

Comment: Ah, StackOverflow removed the things between < and >.. i'm sorry. I will try to fix it somehow..

Comment: Okay, i fixed everything :) so, anyone?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here - I get a different compiler exception "`return type must be 'T' to match overridden member`" on the overidden method, due to the different signatures being the same.  Are you sure that the code you have posted matches what you are attempting to compile?

Comment: So, post a minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem. Classes and everything.

Comment: C# does not support virtual return type covariance. That is, when you override a method, the return type has to be an exact match. You cannot have virtual Mammal M() and then override it with override Cat M().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. You had to make the return type generic:

```
public class BaseClass {
  public virtual T Create<T>() where T : BaseClass, new()  {
   var newClass = new T();
   //initialize newClass by setting properties etc
   return newClass;
  }
 }

 public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  public override T Create<T>() {
   var newClass =  base.Create<T>();
   //initialize newClass with DerivedClass specific stuff
   return newClass;
  }
 }

void Test() {

 DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass() ;
 d.Create<DerivedClass>();
}
```

These are some basic [C# override rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> The overridden base method must have
>   the same signature as the override
>   method.

This means the same return type and same method arguments.

Comment: can you edit 1 more time?  the classes need indenting to format properly AFAICT

Answer (score 2):

Your override cannot change the return type, even if the return type derives from the base class method's return type. You have to do something like what Igor did above, and make the return type generic.